# How many objects are eligible for the garbage collector?

Tags: garbage-collection

Could you please check my solution to the question: "How many objects are eligible for the garbage collector on the line (// custom code)?"

```
class Dog {
    String name;
}

public class TestGarbage {               
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Dog d1 = new Dog();                
        Dog d2 = new Dog();                
        Dog d3 = new Dog();                

        d1 = d3;                                   // line 1
        d3 = d2;                                   // line 2
        d2 = null;                                 // line 3

        // custom code
    }
}
```

What I know from the documenation: "The object will not become a candidate for garbage collection until all references to it are discarded."

Objects and references: (Where A, B and C are the Objects created)

```
d1 -> A
d2 -> B
d3 -> C
------- d1 = d3 ------
d1 -> C
d2 -> B
d3 -> C
------- d3 = d2 ------
d1 -> C
d2 -> B
d3 -> B
------- d2 = null ------
d1 -> C
d2 -> null
d3 -> B
```

A is eligible to delete, so we can say that there is ONLY ONE object which is eligible for the garbage collector!

Is this approach right?

Comment: Could somebody help to answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that only `A`, the first `Dog` object created, is obviously available for collection.

However, if your "custom code" does not include any references to `d1`, `d2`, or `d3` then those variables could be be discarded at any time by the compiler leaving all `Dog` objects as GC candidates.